# Include static file content into Play 2.4 template

Tags: css, templates, playframework, playframework-2.4

I'm using Play framework.

In a template it is possible to do the following to include css.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
```

But what I would like to do is to include the css right into the webpage

```
<style>@[include the static file contents]</style>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I'm just wondering... why would you want to inline your stylesheet file?

Comment: So there is no need for an extra request to get it. It's not a big deal, but why not?

Comment: I strongly recommend to **not** do this. You gain nothing from it. All modern browsers will cache your external stylesheet. It will be transferred only once. Also don't forget the rules of optimization: 1. Don't. 2. Don't yet (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization)

Comment: @Roman If you think of email clients they mostly will not load external stylesheets. So there is a use case.

Answer (score 5):

As others mentioned it is **NOT** preferred way, anyway you can use common ['*tags*' technique](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTemplateUseCases#Tags-(they-are-just-functions-right?)) for doing this,

just create a file `views/tags/yourStyles.scala.html` with content:

```
<style>
    * {
        background: orange;
    }
</style>
```

so in your template/view you can use it as (sample):

```
<head>
    <title>@title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.WebJarAssets.at("images/favicon.png")">
    @tags.yourStyles() <!-- <-here ->
</head>
```